# Provide/Inject in Vue 3 and composition API

Tags: vue.js

I aim to preserve the state of the application. I am using provide in component A and then inject in component B. Finally, I am trying to display the variable in the template of component B.

Nothing is displayed.

I am using Composition API.

Here is the code:

### Component A

```
import { provide } from 'vue';

provide('global', "test");
```

### Component B

```
import { inject } from 'vue';

const global = inject('global');
```

### Template of Component B

```
From A: {{ global }}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is your Componet B a child/ancestor of component A?

Comment: Are you using <script setup>? If not then make sure `provide` and `inject` are both called synchronously inside `setup()`. Is Component B a descendant of Component A?

Comment: @Legit007 Component B is a child of Component A.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem, the snippets aren't enough. If `script setup` is used and the hierarchy is as you said (although it should be explained in the question), it wou;d be workable as is because `global` variable is automatically exposed to a template

Comment: @EstusFlask true, than this was important question from fanoflix, my bad.

Comment: Thanks, @Estus Flask, I used 'script setup,' and now the code works.

Comment: Thanks @Fanoflix, with 'script setup', the code works.